# I am trying to get rid of rows using multiple values, but I am getting an error

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

Here is my code:

```
df = df[df.col not in ['val1','val2','val3']]
df
```

But I get this error:

The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df.col` is a column, i.e. a series, you can't use `in` with it. Try `pd`'s `isin`:

```
 df[~df.col.isin(['val1','val2','val3'])]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df = df[~df.col.isin ['val1','val2','val3']]
```

try like these